# Apache Tika maxStringLength reached

Tags: java, apache, parsing, apache-tika

l have thousands of pdf documents that are 11-15mb. My program says that my document contains more than 100k characters.

Error output:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.tika.sax.WriteOutContentHandler$WriteLimitReachedException:
>   Your document contained more than 100000 characters, and so your
>   requested limit has been reached. To receive the full text of the
>   document, increase your limit.

How can l increase the limit to 10-15mb ?

I found a solution which is new Tika facade class but l could not find a way to integrate it with mine.

```
  Tika tika = new Tika(); 
  tika.setMaxStringLength(10*1024*1024);
```

Here is my code:

```
  BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
  Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
  String location = "C:\\Users\\Laptop\\Dropbox\\MainTextbookTrappe2ndEd.pdf";
  FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(location);
  ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
  PDFParser pdfparser = new PDFParser(); 
  pdfparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);
```

Output:

```
System.out.println("Content of the PDF :" + pcontext);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use

```
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
```

to disable the limit.
From the [Javadoc](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/org/apache/tika/sax/BodyContentHandler.html#BodyContentHandler%28int%29):

> The internal string buffer is bounded at the given number of
>   characters. If this write limit is reached, then a SAXException is
>   thrown.
>  Parameters: `writeLimit` - maximum number of characters to
>   include in the string, or -1 to disable the write limit

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try it when l am home. Isn't disabling the limit dangerous instead of limiting it? If user uploads 10gb trash pdf document, system will destroy or crash.

Comment: @Ali19033 of course you can also simply increase the limit so that you just cover the size of your PDFs.